# The state on C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $C$ be a C*-algebra, $A\subset C$ be a C*-subalgebra of $C$ and $B=A'\cap C$ (here, $A'$ denotes the commutant of $A$). If $\xi$ is a state on $C$ and we take an positive element $b\in B$, then the functionals $a\rightarrow \frac{1}{\xi(b)}\xi(ab)$ is also a state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily, you would need to assume e.g. that $b$ is positive.

Let $C = M_2(\mathbb{C})$, and let $A$ be the subalgebra of diagonal matrices. Take
\begin{align*} \xi  \left( \begin{pmatrix} x & y \\ z & w \\ \end{pmatrix} \right) = \frac{x+w}{2} && b = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}. \end{align*}
or something to that effect. Then taking $a = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0  \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$, which is a positive element of $A$, you get $\frac{1}{\xi(b)} \xi(ab) < 0$, so the "state" is not positive.

Comment: But, if $b$ is positive, how to verify that the functional $a \rightarrow \frac{1}{\xi(b)}\xi(ab)$ is a state?

Comment: And I edited my question.

Comment: Where are you having trouble? Basically, you need to show $a \mapsto \xi(ab)$ is a positive linear functional. The factor $\frac{1}{\xi(b)}$ is just there to normalize.

Comment: If $a \in A$ is positive, then you can write $a = x^*x$ for some $x \in A$. Do you see how to proceed from there?

Comment: Yeah, it is obvious that the functional $f: a \rightarrow \frac{1}{\xi(b)}\xi(ab)$ is positive. But, how to verify it is a state? I mean how to verify $||f||=1$?

Comment: Are you aware of the following fact? If $f$ is a postive linear functional on a unital C*-algebra $A$, then $f(1) = \|f\|$.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14509/discussion-between-belle-tiantian-and-mike-f)

Comment: If C*-algebra has no unit?

Comment: If $f$ is a positive linear functional on a nonunital C*-algebra $A$, then there is a unique positive linear functional $\tilde f$ on the unitization $\tilde A$ which extends $f$ and has $\| \tilde f \| = \|f\|$. One constructs the extension, of course, by putting $\tilde f (1) = \| f\|$, but then one needs to check this extension is positive. You can find proofs of facts such as this in most introductory books on C*-algebras.

Comment: So, proving the functional is a state has nothing to do with the condition $b$ commutes with $A$?

Comment: It has a lot to do with it. You need that condition to make the functional positive!

Comment: Oh, yes, thanks for your patience. :)